# Property id does not exist on type Location

Tags: typescript, angular

I get an build error which looks like this:

```
app/app.component.ts(69,24): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Location'
```

Than I have a function `updateDiv()` which looks like this:

```
updateDiv(location: Location, infoWindow:SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow) {
   this.selectedLocation = location;
   this.ID = location.id;
   this.content = location.content;
 }
```

and here the html:

```
<sebm-google-map-overlay-view *ngFor="let location of locations" (markerClick)="updateDiv(location, infowindow)">
```

How do I declare the property of id and content?

Comment: Can you try a `console.log(location)` in the `updateDiv()` method and look, if it has a `id` field?

Comment: @rinukkusu yes it has: `Object {id: "101", lat: 51.52329594683302, lng: 5.138838711128301, content: "Kids Jungalow Giraffe", iconUrl: "img/marker2.png"}`

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer It has `id` at runtime, however, `Location` class definition does not contains `id`. Use `location['id']` instead.

Comment: Okay, and the `Location` class itself? I just realized, it's a TypeScript error :D

Comment: It is not a class it is an array of markers like this: `  locations: marker[] = [
    {id: '1',  lat: 51.5239935252832,    lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '2',  lat: 51.523853342911906,  lng:  5.1377765563584035,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '3',  lat: 51.5237298485607,    lng:  5.137969675407476,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},`

Comment: and the interface looks like this: `interface marker {
  id: string;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  content: string;
}`

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer if `locations` are `marker[]`, why are you accepting `location: Location`, instead of `location: marker` (in `updateDiv` method)?

Comment: @tchelidze was right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Location'

TypeScript trusts you when you say a function accepts type `Foo` (but you really meant to say its `Bar`). If you try to use it like a `Bar` you get an error like this. You probably didn't mean to say `Location`